# What changes occur in New Game+?

Tags: dead-island

In the "Dead Island" (DI) video-game, what changes occur in New Game+ (NG+), in comparison to the first playthrough?

Acceptable: In particular, I want to know how prices are affected. [Someone](http://www.deadislandforums.com/showthread.php/5648-How-To-Make-Easy-Money-In-D.I?s=b83b6100dacf7cf41603bc06fc9aaa1c&p=74736&viewfull=1#post74736) asserted that diamonds sell for more ($1.65K) rather than $1.5K because of how many times that they've beaten the game.

I am otherwise familiar with the end-game. I don't think it matters but I play on the "OnLive" platform.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Insufficiently definitive? I am usually on the extremely prolific end of the tagger spectrum, so if you're asserting that this site operates on a minimalist criterion of tagging, I'd like you to convince me ASAP.

Comment: [Please see this meta for more info](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012)

Comment: So, from what I understand from [Oak](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/users/122/oak)'s [post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/sorting-out-the-tagging-mess), I can still use the removed tag (i.e. new-game-plus) if I alter it to be more specific so that it fits into the category of tag type 4.
My reasoning for why the "Dead Island new game plus" tags do not fall into the category of tag [type 6](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/sorting-out-the-tagging-mess) is because I expect it to be a searched-for term. For example, people ask what happens to Jin...

Comment: ...and the items stored in her after the end of the game is encountered, fearing that any items in her will be lost. On top of that, I just tried searching for my own question and couldn't find it with the following search terms (prior to the new additions): "Dead Island NG+", "Dead Island new game plus", "Dead Island new game+", and "Dead Island new game +".  
In fact, I found no results, except for searching "[Dead Island new game+](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=dead+island+new+game%2B)" which happened to display three questions which seem not to be related to what I...

Comment: ...expected or what I would expect others to search for and find with those terms. 

Nevermind (for now), I don't have enough reputation to make the new tags: dead-island-new-game-+ dead-island-ng+ dead-island-new-game-plus dead-island-new-game+

Comment: I know that I do not need a tag for the question to show up in searches, yet [searching](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=dead+island+new+game%2B) for terms present in the question + tags which I would expect to yield my question, does not yield my question. This, I can only assert, is folly whose remedy is the addition of tags or revamp of the search system. Try to search for my question yourself. If you manage to find it, please tell me what terms you use that work.

Comment: `[dead-island] new game plus` worked fine for me. Why are all your search links in meta. Am I missing something in your rant?

Answer (score 1):

At a high level / most important, these are the changes when starting with New Game+:

- Collectibles are carried over, such as collected skulls or weapon mod blueprint. Items you got for collectibles will
  not re-appear on your side of a co-op or SP game.
- Your skills / weapon mastery are kept

Some other tweaks include:

- You start on the beach with Castaway (you don't play through the ship
  again).
- All your items on your person and in Henry's storage are accessible
- Team quests results are not saved / carried over.
- If you decide to start a New Game with the same character, you can
  chapter select and start at a pre-set level (increases as you go up
  in chapters) but all your missions (sides, continuous, team) are
  reset.

I don't remember the diamond price being different (or much different, memory little fuzzy) on my second play through. Nor can I found any mention of diamond prices changing in New Game+ on the Internets.

Comment: Henry's storage and team quests are new in Riptide. I was asking about the original Dead Island.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the prices increase a bit each time you complete the game, or the diamonds thing that you said before was a glitch, but if you start new game plus you can select which chapter you start from, and you keep your charactor from your last completion.

Comment: Hi Wade, welcome to Arqade!  We want authoritative, complete answers to the question asked, if possible.  Do you have any sources for your info?  Are you certain the only change is the price increase?  If you'd just like to leave a bit of helpful info for the asker, you can do so with a comment, although you'll have to get a bit of rep before you can leave comments on other people's posts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the prices aren't affected but it is possible also there is a perk that allows you to buy things cheaper and others to buy them for more but this could have only been if you bring a player from the first game and or you are playing the first game

Answer (score -2):

It is also for another playthrough so you won't continually get bored, meaning you can redew the entire storyline with items you have already gotten, also from the beginning the zombies are at your level meaning it raised the difficulty